# Inconsistent behavior of QSerialPort on Debian

Tags: qt, serial-port, qt5, epson

I want to communicate with `Epson TM-H6000iii` via `EscPos` by using QSerialPort 5.5. 
It cancels printing on `serial.close`. When I debugged it can't catch the reason. After spending days I found this case:

1. Reboot machine
2. Run the application. (Printer cancels printing)
3. Debug the application and put breakpoint on serial.close(); (Printer behaves as expected)
4. Now run the application again. (Printer will NEVER STOP PRINTING again on serial.close)

To sum up: if I debug `serial.close` line once then no problem at all.

Any idea?

Comment: I think this may be due to a timeout settings of serial port. Qt doesn't support a timeouts settings, therefore a solution may be platform-dependent...

Comment: You have to provide more information. I do not understand "I debug serial.close". Describe what `QSerialPort` sends and receives. Usually if you send incomplete frame to a printer then it can be in state where restarting application doesn't solve the problem since invalid state is saved on printer side. Serial port doesn't have restart connection functionality.

Comment: Hi. I send ascii characters in my code. I use serial.write then serail.waitforbyteswritten for each command. And all is went well. Then my job finishes. At this point there is serial.close. if i put breakpoint to this line in qtcreator no problem at all. Then i let the debugger to continue. But in the same case AFTER REBOOT if i dont put a breakpoint to serial.close printer cancels printing. If you need more info im ready. Thanks.

Comment: To clarify With AFTER REBOOT i mean rebooting the pc